# Estimation of a population number

Tags: estimation, population, demography

Suppose that we know the population number $n$ of a country in $2014$ for people aged between $0$ and $19$ years what would be a good simple way to estimate the population number between $1$ and $18$ for the same year $2014$? Thank you for your help!

Comment: It depends on the underlying distribution.

Comment: It depends on the birth and death rates since 1995, not the underlying distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "good" way to estimate the a subpopulation is to have a model for birth and death rates.  Here is such a model.

To estimate the size of an age-based subpopulation $N(1 \le a \le 18)$ given some value $N_0=N(0 \le a \le 19)$ in 2014, we need a birth rate model $b(t)$ for the period (1995-2014) *and* a hazard function $H(a)=P(death~at~age=a|still~alive~at~a).$ Let's say that *still-alive-at-time-age-$a$* is given by $S(a)$, and *death-at-age-$a$* is given by $f(a)=-S'(a)$, so the hazard function is $H(a)=f(a)/S(a)=-S'(a)/S(a)$. This is enough for us to build a semi-reasonable model.

Now three big assumptions.

- a constant absolute birth rate $b(t)=B_0$ (probably wrong)
- constant hazard function $H(a)=H_0$ (*not taking into account the naturally-elevated infant mortality !!!*)
- no immigration or emigration (*only Switzerland and the Andaman Islands?*),

We can derive some approximate relations
$$
H(a)=-S'(a)/S(a)=H_0 \implies S(a)=exp(-H_0a)
$$
So survival is an exponentially decreasing function of age.

The surviving cohort in any year is just $B_0exp(-H_0a)$. So the survivors of all cohorts is

$$
\sum_{a=0}^{19}B_0~exp(-H_0a)=B_0\frac{1-exp(-20H_0)}{1-exp(-H_0)}=N_0
$$

We do need to know at least the average birth rate $B_0$ in addition to the population-under-20 $N_0$ in order to estimate $\hat{H_0}=H_0(B_0,N_0)$ numerically.  Once we've done that, the population in the age range from 1 to 18 is just

$$
\sum_{a=1}^{18}B_0~exp(-\hat{H_0}a)=B_0\frac{1-exp(-19\hat{H_0})}{1-exp(-\hat{H_0})}-B_0
$$

Note that in the limit that $\hat{H_0}<<1$, the problem simplifies to the rather pedestrian solution $N(1<age<18) = \frac{18}{20}N_0$.